# Can't use keyboard in IE 11 to navigate Html.DropdownListFor when it is within a Kendo Panelbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I use an `Html.DropdownListFor` from within a Kendo Panelbar (`Html.Kendo().PanelBar()`) in Razor MVC. I can use the up and down arrows on my keyboard to switch between the different items in the dropdown in Chrome and Firefox, but I can't do it in IE 11 (I haven't tested on other versions of IE).

Does anyone know why this is happening and what a possible fix is?

If I use `Html.Kendo().DropdownListFor`, I don't have the problem, but for certain reasons I do not want to use Kendo's `DropdownListFor`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle WAI ARIA role="listbox"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921225/how-to-handle-wai-aria-role-listbox)